# C++ math calculation for determining change using char icons

Tags: c++, math, char

```
    cout << "Your change is " << change << ". Here's your change:";

    char q = '@';  
    double ccounter = 0;
    while(ccounter <= (change - .24)){
        cout << q;  
        ccounter = ccounter + .25;
    }

    char d = '^';
    while(ccounter <= (change - .09))
    {
        cout << d;
        ccounter = ccounter + .10;
    }

    char n = '&';
    while(ccounter <= (change - .04)){
        cout << n;
        ccounter = ccounter + .05;
    }

    char p = '*';
    while(ccounter <= change){
        cout << p;
        ccounter = ccounter + .01;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Once your customer pays you the amount that is greater or equal to 1.87, give them the change using the symbols listed above. So, for example, if your customer paid with 5 dollars, you should print out:

`Your change is 3.13. Here’s your change: $$$^***`

First is the code second block is the prompt.

When the user inputs 3 for what they'd like to pay everything is fine, but 4 gets four penny icons when really it should be three since the change is 0.13.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

thank you guys:)

```
[ * ] = Penny (1 cent)
[ & ] = Nickel (5 cents)
[ ^ ] = Dime (10 cents)
[ @ ] = Quarter (25 cents)
[ $ ] = 1 dollar
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use the debugger, and how to step through the code line by line.

Comment: Short answer; floating point is not great for storing currency amounts, since rounding errors can easily creep in. You should store currency amounts in cents as an integer value.

Comment: Well if you want to become any type of programmer, even a hobbyist one, then you really need to learn how to use a debugger. It's invaluable in situations like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is ending at the wrong time because the `ccounter` variable is accumulating errors from floating point round-off. If you calculate `2 + 0.1 + 0.01 + 0.01 + 0.01`, you get 2.1299999999999994. You should change everything to use integer math, i.e. start with a counter of 213 cents, then subtract 25, 10, 5, and 1 from that. If you stick with integer math, it'll work reliably.

Comment: Ohhhh!! Great point. I believe the prompt required using doubles only.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop termination conditions appear to all have one-off errors. It may be more clear to write the code as:

```
cout << "Your change is " << change << ". Here's your change:";

    char q = '@';  
    double ccounter = 0;
    while((change - ccounter) >= 0.25)
    {
            cout << q;  
            ccounter = ccounter + .25;
    }
    char d = '^';
    while((change - ccounter) >= 0.10)
    {
            cout << d;
            ccounter = ccounter + .10;
    }
    char n = '&';
    while((change - ccounter) >= 0.05)
    {
            cout << n;
            ccounter = ccounter + .05;
    }
    char p = '*';
    while((change - ccounter) >= 0.01 )
    {
            cout << p;
            ccounter = ccounter + .01;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the setup for the loops is the same as yours. The test condition is, in my opinion, written a bit more clearly in mine where (change - ccounter) is the amount of change still left to distribute.

In your last case, while(ccounter <= change), if you have 1 cent, it will enter the loop twice. If written in your style, it should be while(ccounter < change) to enter only once.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I revamped the algorithim actually, if youre interested in seeing it let me know.